# How can I download mp3 files and play them in my app?

Tags: java, file, download, mp3

Could someone show me or teach me how I can download 5 or more mp3 in a file and playing them in my app. I've searched about it but all of people how has asked this, nothing explained it well. I don't want to download only one mp3, but multiple mp3s in a file.here is main.java

```
public class StreamingMp3Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{

private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
public EditText editTextSongURL;

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song duration in milliseconds. Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initView();
}

/** This method initialise all the views in project*/
private void initView() {
    buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
    buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);  
    seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
    seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);
    editTextSongURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextSongURL);
    editTextSongURL.setText(R.string.testsong_20_sec);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

/** Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position*/
private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    seekBarProgress.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause){
         /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(editTextSongURL.getText().toString()); // setup song from http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer. 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
        }else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        }

        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay){
        /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
     /** MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song playing is complete*/
    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}
```

Comment: What technology is your app written in? And what have you already done? Because I'm quite sure MP3 players are readily available in most technologies.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not in Java :) You'll need to use 3rd party libraries to support MP3 playback. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives
For the downloading part, use `URLConnection` to get an InputStream.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I'd call certain third party libraries readily available. ;-) But indeed, it depends on the technology. May I suggest that you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use 3rd party libraries to support MP3 playback, as it is not included in the standard library. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives) for a list of alternatives.

For the downloading part, use an `URLConnection` to get an `InputStream` on the file and write it to a `FileOutputStream`. This might help, too: [Working unbuffered Streams](http://codeisland.org/2012/working-unbuffered-streams/)